# Detecting and counting signals in list data: checking pulse rate

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data-acquisition

Hope this isn't too much of a basic question: I'm looking for some Mathematica functions, but I don't know which ones.

*Background*

I recently read about a simple technique for reading your body's pulse rate using the camera built into the computer (eg an iSight camera at the top of an iMac). The idea is that you put your finger over the camera in a reasonably well-lit room, record a movie (about 15 - 20 seconds), then analyze the frames for varying light intensities, which somehow indicate your pulse. So far the technique seems to be promising. The code is:

```
getDataFromList[frames_] := 
  Module[{},
   Mean[Flatten[ImageData[#]]] & /@ 
        (ColorSeparate[#][[1]]  (* red channel is best? *)
    & /@ frames)];

AbsoluteTiming[
      testFrames = CurrentImage[200];
      testData = getDataFromList[testFrames]]

ListLinePlot[testData]
```

The `testData` starts off like this:

```
{0.193808, 0.196383, 0.197617, 0.198657, 0.200555, 0.201459,  
 0.201391, 0.1975, 0.197983, 0.198238, 0.200564, 0.201397, 0.202331,  
 0.20271, 0.199668, 0.196999, 0.197857, 0.19826, 0.199329, 0.200624,  
 0.201472, 0.202583, 0.199393, 0.198472, 0.199569, 0.200466, 0.201441,  
 0.203286, etc.
```

When plotted, the data for me and my left forefinger looks like it might be working (or could at least be a vaguely human pulse):

[image: my pulse]

The data is probably too large to include here - but some of you might have cameras and fingers too, and could generate something similar? In this plot there looks to be about 24 pulses, and the time from `AbsoluteTiming` was 16.965258, so my pulse rate was about 84. (So holding my finger up to the screen was hard work, obviously...)

*Question*

Which Mathematica functions can I use to extract the actual pulse rate from this and similar sets of data?

Comment: Surprisingly, it didn't add a comment when I voted as a duplicate... This is the question, for others: [Can one find the beat of a tune with Fourier analysis?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4272/5)

Comment: @R.M I don't know, a question on beat detection of a tune seems like a big overkill for this

Comment: I suggest to reopen. The other question asked for Fourier, and there are a lot of other possible techniques for doing this (autocorrelation, vanishing derivative, second derivative sign alternating, ...)

Comment: I hadn't thought to look for sound-related questions but you're all right, it's only data after all...

Comment: Voting to reopen. The processing for extracting the pulse rate from this data is likely to look significantly different from that used to extract the beat of a tune.

Comment: @cormullion, besides analyzing the pulse rate, there are other interesting parameters to investigate. E.g. pulse rate variability is an indicator of stress, see http://research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/publications/bsn09_choi.pdf So if there are more parameters to detect, it is not really the same question as the other one. Also, input could be from a "R-R" pulse meter that measures pulse over a longer period of time (difficult to have your laptop stuck to your finger..:-)

Comment: Good to see it was reopened.

Comment: @belisarius please show us one now. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I made up some code, but it is very similar to Rojo's last lines.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's invent some data. The pulse rate will be 50

```
pulseRate = 50;
sampleRate = 1000;
data = Range[0, 1, 1/sampleRate] /. 
 t_ :> Sin[2. Pi pulseRate t] + 8 Sinc[Pi t 2.]^2 // # + 
 RandomReal[0.3 {-1, 1}, Length@#] &;
ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> {0, 200}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plotting `Fourier` already shows it will be easy to extract the value

```
ListLinePlot[Abs@Fourier[data], PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, Full}, 
 DataRange -> {0, sampleRate}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For whatever reason, let's filter it a little bit first

```
filteredData = data~MovingAverage~10~DerivativeFilter~{1};
ListLinePlot[filteredData]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we see more cleary that the peaks are in the pulse rate

```
ListLinePlot[Abs@Fourier[filteredData], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, Full}, DataRange -> {0, sampleRate}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In a general case we could be more careful finding the peaks but, let's just find the 2 maximums and their corresponding frequency

```
(Ordering[Abs@Fourier[filteredData], -2] - 1) Length@data/sampleRate // N
```

> {50.05, 942.942}

```
Abs@Mod[%, 1000, -500]
```

> {50.05, 57.058}

It's a start

**Another quick approach**

This would give an indicator vector with ones where there's a peak (local maximum or minimum)

```
peaks = Unitize@Differences@Sign@Differences[data~MovingAverage~10];
```

This would give the number of samples between peaks

```
peakIntersamples = Differences@Flatten@Position[peaks, 1];
```

From that we can estimate the pulse rate

```
sampleRate/Median@peakIntersamples/2
```

> 50

Comment: @cormullion it has now been unclosed :). But even if you feel like accepting, have an open mind about changing the accept in the future: I have the feeling a couple of good answers may be coming now it has been reopen ;D

Comment: `data~MovingAverage~10~DerivativeFilter~{1}` ... damn

Comment: @belisarius infix fits those kind of functions perfectly, right? :)

Comment: @rojo Your answer was obviously the last word in the subject! Thanks  - it was very helpful.